# Remove top link by title not by url in xml

Tags: xml, toplinks

I've got 2 top links with the same url. I need to remove one of them on a specific handle.

Removing by url will exclude both of them.

Is there a xml solution to this? Like removing by title.

Thanks!

Example of a link:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
    <label>Account</label>
    <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>
    <title>Account</title>
    <prepare/>
    <urlParams/>
    <position>1</position>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported out of the box.
The top links are rendered by the block `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links` that allow you to remove a link only by url or by block.
An option would be to make your link be rendered by a block and then use `removeLinkBlock`.
See how to add a block in the `checkout.xml` [layout file](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml#L38).
Or you can rewrite the `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links` and create a new method called `removeLinkByTitle`

```
public function removeLinkByTitle($title)
{
    foreach ($this->_links as $k => $v) {
        if ($v->getTitle() == $title) {
            unset($this->_links[$k]);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

and you can use that similar to `removeLinkByUrl`

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to remove the link by title. But you can achieve this by [**rewrite**](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) the class `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links`.

And add the below function

```
public function removeLinkByTitle($title)
{
    foreach ($this->_links as $k => $v) {
        if ($v->getTitle() == $title) {
            unset($this->_links[$k]);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Now you can remove the link by title with below code.

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="removeLinkByTitle"><title>Account</title></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extending the core like the other answers, just remove them both and re-add the one you'd like to stay. For example if you've two links with the `customer/getAccountUrl` url:

```
<reference name="top.links"> 
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
        <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl" />
    </action>
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>Account</label>
        <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>
        <title>Account</title>
        <prepare/>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>1</position>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Please add more details, so that the answer is useful in its own. Otherwise it would have been more suitable as a comment to one of the other answers

Comment: I've added a example.